# How to Make an OnClick Event in a RecylcerView Java

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm having an issue trying to create an OnClickListener in my CategoriesAdapter.Java

A short summary of what i'm trying to do: I am trying to build a section of an app that shows the 'Categories' of certain business types i.e. Tech, Finance etc etc

I want to make sure the user is able to click on a category and take them to that desired category of choice basically; "User clicks on 'Finance' User goes to 'Finance' Category.

I'll paste my code here if you can help me that would be great.

CategoriesAdapter.Java

```
package com.example.tencil.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter;


import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tencil.R;
import com.example.tencil.User.CategoriesHelperClass;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<CategoriesHelperClass> categories;
private ArrayList<CategoriesHelperClass> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<CategoriesHelperClass> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
private android.content.Context mcontext;



public CategoriesAdapter(ArrayList<CategoriesHelperClass> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mImages = mImages;
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
}



//Returns Categories View Dynamically
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.categories_card_design, parent, false );
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder ( view );
    return new ViewHolder ( view );
}

public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Log.d (TAG, "OnBindViewHolder: Called.");
    holder.image.setImageResource ( com.example.tencil.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.CategoriesHelperClass.getImage () );
    holder.title.setText ( com.example.tencil.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.CategoriesHelperClass.getTitle () );
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d (TAG, "OnClick: Clicked on" + mImages.get ( position ));
            Toast.makeText ( mcontext, (CharSequence) mTitle.get ( position ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );


}

public int getItemCount() {

    return categories.size ();
}

//HOLDS VIEWS
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );


        //HOOKS
        image = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.categories_image );
        title = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.categories_title );
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.parentLayout );



    }

    }
}
```

UserDashboard.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".User.UserDashboard">


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:theme="@style/navigationTheme"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="20dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/app_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/tencil"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="28sp" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/card_1"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/card_3"
                            android:elevation="8dp"
                            android:onClick="cardClicked1">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/tencilw" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:text="@string/socialmedis"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/card_2"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/card_1"
                            android:elevation="8dp"
                            android:onClick="cardClicked2">>

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/piggy" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="@string/finance"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/card_3"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/card_2"
                            android:elevation="8dp"
                            android:onClick="cardClicked3">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/pws" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="@string/tech"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/card_4"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/card_4"
                            android:elevation="8dp"
                            android:onClick="cardClicked4">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/analysisw" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="@string/fintech"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/banner_background">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/featured_background"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="280dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/banner_background"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                            android:text="@string/featured_companies"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="25dp" />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/featured_companies_description" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/featured_recycler"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/featured_background"
                        android:background="#fff" />


                </RelativeLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
                            android:text="@string/categories"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/view_all"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:onClick="viewAllClicked"
                            android:text="@string/view_all" />


                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                        android:layout_height="150dp" />



                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

CategoriesHelperClass.java

```
    package com.example.tencil.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter;

public class CategoriesHelperClass {
    static int image;
    static String title;

    //SETTER
    public CategoriesHelperClass(int image, String title) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    //GETTER
    public static int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public static String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


}
```

CONSOLE ERROR MESSAGE

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tencil, PID: 5226
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.tencil.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.CategoriesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoriesAdapter.java:55)
    at com.example.tencil.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.CategoriesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoriesAdapter.java:25)
```

Any help would be appreciated this has been bugging me for hours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. From the error message, looks that `holder.parentLayout` is null. Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the error message properly.

Comment: Hi Guys , I'm now getting the following: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Answer (score 0):

this is how you would solve this problem from kotlin using callbacks, in java you need to use listeners

in your `Activity`/`Fragment` have a function ready to handle the navigation like this

Note that the code below is like a pseudo code and you will have to adjust accordingly

```
private fun navigateTo(title: String) {
    //handle navigation with the title normally here
    val intent = Intent(this, Category::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Title", title)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

in your Activity's onCreate

```
val categoriesAdapter = CategoriesAdapter({ title ->
        navigateTo(title)
    })
```

here's the Adapter and ViewHolder classes

```
private class CategoriesAdapter(val callBack:(String)-> Unit){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(): CategoriesViewHolder{
        return CategoriesViewHolder(callBack)
    }
}

private class CategoriesViewHolder(val callBack: (String) -> Unit){
    fun bind(){
        item.setOnClickListener{
            callBack(title)
        }
    }
}
```

what this does is when you click a certain item, you will get the title and any detail you want from inside the view holder's bind method which will contain only 1 single item inside at any given time, and that will run the method named `callBack` and sends the title for it back to the adapter, and the adapter does nothing but call the same method again and sends title for it in the `Activity`, then your `Activity` will run `navigateTo` method and do the action required.

in java, you will create a `Listener` inside your `Activity`/`Fragment` and you will use it directly from your ViewHolder if i remember correctly and this will do the same effect

Comment: Thank you for your response I will attempt this shortly

Comment: Hi Guys , I'm now getting the following: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: sometimes it outputs this error in logs but it works correctly, unless u are not getting any view on screen then it's ok

Answer (score 0):

In java, you must cast each element of view to its class, `findViewById()` returns member of `T` class, so you will get normal View instead ImageView, TextView etc.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );
        //HOOKS
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.categories_image );
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.categories_title );
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.parentLayout );
    }
}
```

In addition, if you want to click whole row, you should use `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener()`. Calling click listener on RelativeLayout will work only, when you touch a free space in your row view, so it may not work each time.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will attempt this shortly

Comment: Hi Guys , I'm now getting the following: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: @RyanKimber Does something still not working?

Comment: Hi Guys, is there a way to make the on click listener cycle through an array?

Comment: @RyanKimber Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776974/5712938) will help you.

Answer (score -1):

get data from list and set to view (in onBindViewHolder method)

```
        CategoriesHelperClass item = categories.get(position);

        holder.image.setImageResource ( item.getImage () );
        holder.title.setText ( item.getTitle () );
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d (TAG, "OnClick: Clicked on" + mImages.get ( position ));
                Toast.makeText ( mcontext, item.getTitle (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
            }
        } );
```

there is no need for this two list, you can handle image and image with categories list

```
private ArrayList<CategoriesHelperClass> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<CategoriesHelperClass> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I will attempt this shortly

Comment: Hi Guys , I'm now getting the following: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout